# MailItem.SaveAs when referencing with EntryID

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm developing a drag and drop of a MailItem from Outlook (I know it's a MailItem and not any other type) into an Access memo field. Trying to call SaveAs on a MailItem object.

I get

> Error 287 - Application-defined or object-defined error.

I've tried using the namespace, not using the namespace, using .Item, etc.

Here's my current code:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olNs.GetItemFromID(olNs.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)

olMail.SaveAs strPathAndFile, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG
```

Access 2010, Outlook 2010 both 32 bit. Win 7 machine is 64 bit.

Tried it on an all 32-bit machine, same error.

Tried Dmitry's code below, same error.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this working using Dmitry Streblechenko's awesome [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) library. Thanks!

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim oRDOSession As Redemption.RDOSession
Set oRDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
oRDOSession.MAPIOBJECT = olNs.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT

If Not oRDOSession.LoggedOn Then oRDOSession.Logon

Dim oMsgItem As Redemption.RDOMail
Set oMsgItem = oRDOSession.GetMessageFromID(olNs.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)

strPathAndFile = "some\path\" & UniqueValueStr(Now()) & ".msg"

oMsgItem.SaveAs strPathAndFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to use Redemption?

I don't see any difference between using the OOM and Redempton.

Why do you need to use the [GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893(v=office.15).aspx) method in the code?

> olNs.GetItemFromID(olNs.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)

You have already got a reference to the selected object in the explorer window:

```
olNs.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
```

Also I'd suggest breaking the chaing of calls and declaring each property or method call on a separate line.