# Executing the SaveAs method in Excel for a MailItem object using late binding techniques

Tags: vba, excel

Alright, I'm stuck on why the .SaveAs method will not work in the code below. I have verified that the Type is always correct, MailItem. The .Display method works but the .SaveAs doesn't. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
    Dim applOutlook As Object
    Dim nsOutlook As Object
    Dim myFolder As Object
    Dim myFolderItems As Object
    Dim cssItem As Object
    Dim timeStamp As String
    Dim strName As String

    On Error Resume Next
      Set applOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          Set applOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      End if
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set nsOutlook = applOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = nsOutlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Test")
    Set myFolderItems = myFolder.Items

      For Each cssItem In myFolder.Items
          timeStamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddHhNnSs")
          strName = "C:\Temp\CSSADMIN\" & timeStamp & ".txt"
          Debug.Print TypeName(cssItem)
          cssItem.Display
          'cssItem.SaveAs strName, olTXT
      Next

    Set applOutlook = Nothing
    Set nsOutlook = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
    Set myFolderItems = Nothing
```

Comment: What's `olTXT`? If you're not referencing the Outlook type library and you're not declaring an `olTXT` constant anywhere, then it's an undeclared variable with a value of `Empty`, converted to `0` when passed to a `Long` parameter. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, so undeclared variables keep your code from being compilable.

Comment: Hmm, seems [olTXT's underlying value *is* 0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/olsaveastype-enumeration-outlook), so that wouldn't be it. Still a good idea to declare that constant if you're going to use it.

Comment: I agree with you on olTXT and thank you for the input. However, changing it to 0 didn't fix it. Even after verifying cssItem is a "MailItem," I still get the "Run-time error '287':  Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Of course it didn't fix it (cf. previous comment). But now you can put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and have compilable code.

Comment: It does compile; that's correct. It just doesn't run.

Comment: Does the folder C:\Temp\CSSADMIN\ already exist ?

Comment: Yes, I have a script in Outlook VBA that writes to it all day. My goal is to migrate that code from Outlook to Excel.

Comment: Is anyone else actually able to replicate the problem?

Comment: Similar Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148947/mailitem-saveas-refuses-to-work,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328068/runtime-error-287-sending-emails-through-outlook-using-vba-in-access