# SaveAs msg add userform information to file name

Tags: vba, userform

I've been trying to find a way to modify the SaveAs code to include Me.EvalID_T1.Text  userform information into the title of the message.

I know I am missing something, but not sure what it is. Any help would be great!

Thanks!

```
Dim strPrompt As String, strname As String
Dim sreplace As String, mychar As Variant, strdate As String
Dim M As String            ' variable used to store userform info
M = Me.EvalID_T1.Text     ' userform info
    For Each mychar In Array("/", "\", ":", "?", Chr(34), "<", ">", "¦")
       strname = Replace(strname, mychar, sreplace)
       strdate = Replace(strdate, mychar, sreplace)
   Next mychar
    myPath = "C:\Users\cam\Desktop\Test\ & " - path to save file
    If myPath = False Then
        MsgBox "No directory chosen !", vbExclamation
    Else
    On Error Resume Next
        olmail.SaveAs myPath & M & ".msg", olMsg   ' unknown how to modify
```

Comment: It looks as myPAth has excess spaces and & sign at the end. Why don't you put path in a var and check format?

Comment: Good point. That gave me an idea I remember when I save it had a "&" in the name ... wonder... also thinking can I still access the userform information at this point?  I'll try a few things. Thanks!

Comment: update so the desktop\Test\   anything after the Test is the name of the message  so I thought to add variable with what I needed after   me.EvalID_T1.text   no luck.. just reads as text and value the same.  current  like now ()  no luck... hmmm just got it to read to the file...

Comment: have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148947/mailitem-saveas-refuses-to-work ?