# Issue with Class Module Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am new to VBA and am trying to insert a class module to save an email that arrives to a sub-folder in the inbox called "My Folder" to a location on a sharedrive. I have the below code and have tried sending emails to test but it is not working and cannot figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Sub Application_Startup()
Dim xNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set xNameSpace = Outlook.Application.Session
Set InboxItems = xNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set InboxItems = olFolder.Folders("My Folder")
End Sub

Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal objItem As Object)
Dim FSO
Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xFilePath As String
Dim xRegEx
Dim xFileName As String
On Error Resume Next
xFilePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
xFilePath = xFilePath & "File Path on Share Drive will be entered here"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FolderExists(xFilePath) = False Then
FSO.CreateFolder (xFilePath)
End If
Set xRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
xRegEx.Global = True
xRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
xRegEx.Pattern = "\||\/|\<|\>|""|:|\*|\\|\?"
If objItem.Class = olMail Then
Set xMailItem = objItem
xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, "")
xMailItem.SaveAs xFilePath & "\" & xFileName & ".msg", olMSG
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Never would try such thing in Outlook, even less in VBA. But just one question: how would the application know to call `InboxItems_ItemAdd`? Where is it registered as event handler? If the method is fired, please be more specific on *what exactly does not work and how exactly do you get notified about this*. On the other hand: you set `InboxItems` then you overwrite its value immediately, why?

Comment: Appreciate the response. Like I mentioned, I am new to VBA and am trying to piece together items that I find. It is certainly not my strong suit. I found a forum where people said the framework of the above worked for them in a similar manner, and I tried to tailor it to suit my needs. I just want outlook to save a copy of any email that comes to a specific folder to a location on a sharedrive. Are you saying you would never do such a thing? Thanks for your help

Comment: I would use .net to write a plugin for outlook... but that's my way. It is not that it would not work, I am just not a VBA fan, if there are better methods...

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Set InboxItems = xNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders('My Folder')`? Are you sure, that ApplicationStartup is the place of initialization? Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd I see an `Initialize_handler` override(?).

Comment: Just as option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-perform-actions-when-an-e-mail-message-is-received?view=vs-2017

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Zorgo. Unfortunately, all I have access to is VBA. Are you saying I should remove the ApplicationStartup sub and replace it with the Initialize_handler?

Comment: It was just an idea...

Comment: Are you getting an error, any idea *where* this is failing?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues with the code that I saw. I have this working, make sure you add this to the `ThisOutlookSession` object in the VBA IDE.

```
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application: Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace: Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set InboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim FolderPath      As String: FolderPath = "YOUR PATH HERE"
    Dim FileName        As String
    Static FSO          As Object

    If FSO Is Nothing Then Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) = False Then FSO.CreateFolder FolderPath

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\||\/|\<|\>|""|:|\*|\\|\?"

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            FileName = .Replace(Item.Subject, vbNullString)
            Item.SaveAs FolderPath & FileName & ".msg", olMSG
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks so much! Unfortunately, it is still not working on my end. I have sent multiple test emails. I am in a corporate environment and have tried using Public instead of Private. Do you have any suggestions to get this working? Really appreciate your help

Comment: The code should work, however, few things to check.Make sure you've updated the FolderPath variable. Make sure macros are enabled all the time. See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6. If that doesn't work, SaveAs apparently can be finicky. You might need to use Redemption. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148947/mailitem-saveas-refuses-to-work

Comment: Oh, and triple check you added this to `ThisOutlookSession` not a module or a class.